# What is the purpose of sonar-maven3-plugin?

Tags: maven, maven-3, sonarqube

I want to analyze a Maven 3 project. I found the following plugins:

- org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.0
- org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven-plugin:3.6.2
- org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven3-plugin:3.6.2

So I can run Sonar analysis with 3 ways:

```
mvn org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.0:sonar (or simply mvn sonar:sonar since the package is org.codehaus.mojo)
```

or

```
mvn org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven-plugin:3.6.2:sonar
```

or

```
mvn org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven3-plugin:3.6.2:sonar
```

What is the most appropriate way for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the different groupIDs of the plugins you mentioned, this is explained here:
[What is the difference between org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin and org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven-plugin?](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Frequently+Asked+Questions#FrequentlyAskedQuestions-Whatisthedifferencebetweenorgcodehausmojosonar-maven-pluginandorgcodehaussonarsonar-maven-plugin)

Comment: Link doesn't work. New http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/HOME/Frequently+Asked+Questions#FrequentlyAskedQuestions-Whatisthedifferencebetweenorg.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-pluginandorg.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven-plugin?

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+Maven) is clear about that: you just have to execute `mvn sonar:sonar` to run your analysis, no need to worry about anything else - SonarQube handles that for you.

Comment: Where do I report issues?  For example, this page says the opposite and perhaps needs to be updated-> http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+Maven